# django-haystack with solr gives error

Tags: django, django-haystack, solr4

I am using latest version of django-haystack and solr 4.6.0. It returns the error code `400`

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":3},"error":{"msg":"no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param","code":400}}
```

Comment: How you performed the query?

Comment: I have not much idea about django-haystack i just followed the tutorial http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html please help.